# JPA: Using "long fooId" instead of "Foo foo" as @JoinColumn possible (for JSON compat)?

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa

I've two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int, ...);
CREATE TABLE bar (id int, foo_id int, FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo (id));
```

The typical way to create the JPA model class for `bar` would be (shortened):

```
@Entity
class Bar {
     @Id
     long id;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn("foo_id")
     Foo foo;
}
```

Problem is, I want to use this model class for JAX-RS as well and if I receive a new Bar class via the REST service, it only contains a single `foo_id` attribute which can't be mapped to the attribute `foo` of type `Foo`.

I've already tried the following, i.e. mapping the table column `foo_id` twice, once into a numeric id and once into an object, but that did confuse JPA, too:

```
...
@Column("foo_id")
long foo_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn("foo_id", insertable=false, updateable=false)
Foo foo;
```

What's the general approach here? Should I use foo_id in REST and foo in Java and translate between them in my REST boundary class i.e. load the foo object from database before persisting it?

Comment: `if I receive a new Foo class via the REST service, it only contains a single foo_id attribute` : do you mean `Bar` object or `Foo`? You better post the relevant code so that we might see where your problem lies.

Comment: you're right, I changed it to `Bar`. The original class has too much code that is not relevant and class names that are specific to my employer. It my problem is not clear, i'd rather write a small demo on github but I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use this model class for JAX-RS as well and if I receive a new Foo class via the REST service, it only contains a single foo_id attribute which can't be mapped to the attribute foo of type Foo.

It depends on what you want to do with your objects:

1. If you just want to use an instance of `Foo` in your application without synchronizing with the database, just fetch the `Foo` object from the database using the `foo_id` as:

   ```
   Foo foo = entityManager.find(Foo.class, foo_id`);
   ```

   and assign this instance to the `foo` field of the `Bar` class.
2. If you want to synchronize the `bar` object with the database merge it as follows:

   ```
   Bar bar = entityManager.merge(bar);
   ```

   Then fetch the `Foo` object as in `1.` for the `foo_id` and assign it to the `foo` field of the `bar` object.

> I've already tried the following, i.e. mapping the table column foo_id twice, once into a numeric id and once into an object, but that did confuse JPA

I, personally, don't like this idea. You should not forget that you want to write code that is understandable by your colleagues and even by yourself a couple of months later. It would be difficult to comprehend for someone why you do so even if JPA allow you to do so!

Comment: It the Bar model class would not contain a "long fooId" attribute, the REST mapper would throw an Exception if the incoming request contained a "foo_id". I would have to duplicate the Bar class and have one version for REST/JSON and one, slightly different version, as JPA model. While that might be good anyway to keep a stable external API in the REST service, I hoped that I could avoid the duplication.in a simple project.

Comment: I do not understand the problem because you haven't posted the REST interface; at least the relevant part of the interface where you are facing the problem might help to see if there is a better solution.